# Canonical toList in java?

Tags: java, collections

Is there something like this in any standard library (e.g. apache-commons, guava) ?

```
public static <T> List<T> toList(Iterable<T> iterable) {
    if (iterable instanceof List)
        return (List<T>)iterable;

    if (iterable instanceof Collection)
        return new ArrayList<T>((Collection<T>)iterable);

    List<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T item : iterable)
        result.add(item);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why are you looking for a library to replace a code that's three lines long?

Comment: @Peter - no particular reason. But, it's code I'm writing over and over in different projects, so if it does exist somewhere I'd like to know.

Comment: Create a utility function (`static`) in one of your classes.

Comment: @Peter - already done. I'm saying this pops up in different projects, not sharing the same code base.

Comment: *Why are you looking for a library to replace a code that's three lines long?* because that's what helper libraries are for: removing boilerplate code.

Comment: @Peter, @S.P, I updated my question to support Iterable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think so, because your implementation does two completely different things:

- If the argument is a list, it returns it. The returned list will therefore be a "live view" of the argument. Changes to each of the lists are visible in the other.
- If the argument is not a list, it returns a copy of it. The returned list will be independent of the argument.

These two things are so different that no sane general-purpose library would throw them together in one method.

Comment: Very good answer (just like Jon Skeet's deleted answer). I can understand the need for such a method, but the implications would be awful.

Comment: I can't believe that I still can't see deleted answers. How about http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71045/feature-request-see-deleted-posts

Comment: +1 for being pretty much *exactly* our reason for not including this in Guava.

Comment: Then why not have a method that always does the second thing, no matter what?

Comment: That is already available in Guava's `Lists.newArrayList(...)`.